# Scaling Image beyond screen in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to scale an image so that it is zoomed in, and the rest of the image is beyond the screen. I already tried the scaling property but it didn't seem to affect my image size.

[image]

Is there a property that I can use to achieve this?

```java
class animationPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            'assets/imageMain.JPG',
            height: 300,
            scale: 2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code that isn't working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `InteractiveViewer` widget to add interactions to your widgets. It supports `pan` and `scale` interactions.

I added a demo on how to use the widget using your code as an example:

1. Define a transformation controller:

```
final transformationController = TransformationController();
```

2. Use the `InteractiveViewer` widget:

```
    InteractiveViewer(
      transformationController: transformationController, // pass the transformation controller
      onInteractionEnd: (details) {
        setState(() {
          transformationController.toScene(
              Offset.zero); // return to normal size after scaling has ended
        });
      },
      boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      minScale: 0.1, // min scale
      maxScale: 4.6, // max scale
      scaleEnabled: true,
      panEnabled: true,
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/imageMain.JPG',
        height: 300,
      ),
    );
```

Read more about the `InteractiveViewer` widget here:

[Interactive Viewer article](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/interactive-viewer-in-flutter-69d3def22a4f)

[InteractiveViewer documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html)

Note: Your `Flutter` version has to be `1.20` for you to be able to use the widget.

Comment: Is it possible to work without a setState()? I'm working with a statelessWidget so I can't implement such a method.

Comment: Hi @spamup, just seeing this comment, if you wish to use the `InteractiveViewer` in a `Stateless` widget. You can.

Answer (score 2):

You can also mess around with wrapping the image in the `FittedBox` widget... using it usually helps with sizing its `child` and it's got lots of good parameters you can set to get it to work specific to your use-case. There's also good [documentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4Uehk3_wlY).

Secondly, you could wrap it in a `InteractiveViewer` widget, although this may not be ideal.

Finally, you could potentially wrap your image in a `Transform.scale` widget and change its `scale` parameter.